# Active merchant Rails 4. Step by step

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Tell me how to incrementally integrate the payment process in the application on the rails 4. All that I found - for rails 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this link, it may help you [Integrate active merchant in rails 3.2](http://active-merchant-rails3.blogspot.com/)

It also contains a sample app on github.